# Generic Class with JavaPoet

Tags: java, javapoet

Hey I'm trying to generate a class like this:

```
public abstract class ResourceListAdapter<T extends ResourceViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<T> {}
```

At the moment I can generate:

```
public abstract class ResourceListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<?> {}
```

With following code:

```
TypeSpec type = TypeSpec.classBuilder(thisClass)
    .superclass(ParameterizedTypeName.get(adapterClassName, WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(Object.class)))
    .addModifiers(Modifier.ABSTRACT, Modifier.PUBLIC)
    .build();
```

I'm also able to do something like this:

```
private ResourceListAdapter<? extends ResourceViewHolder> adapter;
```

With:

```
ParameterizedTypeName.get(thisClass,WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(resourceViewHolderClassName));
```

But I'm not able to combine this. So do you have any ideas??

Answer (score 15):

I got a solution!

```
TypeSpec type = TypeSpec.classBuilder(thisClass)
            .superclass(ParameterizedTypeName.get(adapterClassName, TypeVariableName.get("T")))
            .addTypeVariable( TypeVariableName.get("T", resourceViewHolderClassName))
```

Will generate:

```
public abstract class ResourceListAdapter<T extends ResourceViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<T> {}
```